# Show Available space for various Drives in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, memory

On left side of Nautilus, Various Drives and Device List appears,

I want it show used  memory and available memory bar (like Windows) below drive names , is there any way i can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my version of ubuntu (lucid) I don't think I can change it that way, but You can try to use in terminal

`gconf-editor`

and go to schemas/apps/nautilus/preferences and see if You have any option that could do it

Comment: no option   :(:(:(